# How does OS X detect a PowerPC application?

Tags: macos, terminal, applications, powerpc

I use an application called Anki for learning foreign languages and professional terminology.
This app creates a default folder in `/Users/user/Documents/Anki`, which I did not want.

You can circumvent this by calling the app from the CLI with the `-b` option. Because of that, I went into the app bundle and looked for executable in `Anki.app/Contents/MacOs/`, which is simply called `Anki`.

I renamed this file to `Anki2` and made a new executable called `Anki`, which simply reads:

```
/Applications/Anki.app/Contents/MacOS/Anki2 -b /Users/henrikgiesel/Library/Application\ Support/Anki
```

And I can open the App bundle perfectly fine!... Until the next reboot, then it will complain:

*You can’t open the application “Anki.app” because PowerPC applications are no longer supported.*

Why is this? How does OS X detect PowerPC application? Would it work if I wrote a C-file doing basically the same and putting the compiled version in the place of the Shell script?

**EDIT:**

I can still open it from the CLI like this:

```
/Applications/Anki.app/Contents/MacOS/Anki
```

But not like this

```
open /Applications/Anki.app
```

Comment: The title of this question is misleading / not helpful, because obviously you’re not actually dealing with PowerPC code, OS X just misidentifies something.

Comment: But the OS thinks it deals with PowerPC code, so it would be helpful to know, what causes this behavior.

Comment: What version of OS X are you running?

Comment: El Capitan 10.11.2

Answer (score 2):

Try wrapping the shell script as an app using [Platypus](http://sveinbjorn.org/platypus). I've packaged multiple perl and bash scripts using the program, all appear as simple applications, with an icon of your choice, none have ever been misidentified as PPC apps.